# Navigating to Date & Time Settings from Flutter App on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, date, settings

I'm working on a Flutter mobile application where I need to provide users with a shortcut to the device's Date & Time settings when they press a button. For the iOS version of the app, I am considering opening the settings URL directly with something like:

```
const url = 'App-Prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME';
```

However, I am unsure if this approach is compliant with Apple's App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, I have concerns about whether using such a URL scheme to directly navigate to the system settings might lead to rejection during the app review process.

Does anyone have experience with this type of functionality in a published iOS app? Is there a recommended or safer way to achieve similar functionality without risking app store rejection?

Any guidance or insights on navigating to iOS system settings from a Flutter app, while ensuring compliance with App Store policies, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Directly opening the Date & Time settings page on iOS using a custom URL scheme is not recommended and may violate Apple's App Store Review Guidelines. Apple discourages the use of private APIs and direct navigation to specific sections of the Settings app, as it could potentially disrupt the user experience or lead to security vulnerabilities.

Instead, consider using a Flutter package called system_settings, which allows you to open the system and app settings pages on both iOS and Android. Here's how you can use it:

1. Add [system_settings](https://pub.dev/packages/system_settings) to your pubspec.yaml file:

   **dependencies:
   system_settings: ^2.1.0**
2. List item

   **SystemSettings.getDate();**

This approach complies with Apple's guidelines because it opens the general settings page instead of trying to access a specific section directly. It also provides a consistent experience across both platforms.

Remember that even though this package may not explicitly mention opening the Date & Time settings, it's designed to open the relevant settings page, which aligns with Apple's guidelines

Comment: That package will open your own app's settings page, which is all that is supported on iOS.